# TFS2012 only nightly Deployment with MSBuild

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2012

We have configured TFS for Continuous Integration so that whenever the developer checks in, the build is triggered. I know we can use `MSWebDeploy` to deploy the application to IIS. But what I want is the deployment should happen only at night, not for all builds, any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Setup another build definition and set a scheduled trigger for once a night at a certain time. Only pass the arguments to MSBuild to trigger a deployment for this build definition, and not for the CI one.